# establish a condition in async form in c#

Tags: c#, wpf, synchronization

I have a problem that is when I call an async method, it enters and comes up against a condition that I have set, where it sends me an exception that says:

> "The subprocess making the call can not access this object because the
>   owner is another thread.",

I just want the condition process to run in the background with the async method

```
    private Task ObtenerDatosd()
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            for (int i = draw2.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                if (draw2[i].ToString().ToLower().Contains(SearcInterno.Text.ToLower()))
                {
                    //action
                    System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Code action");
                }

            }

        });
    }
```

Comment: Put this line of code before the `Task.Run` - `var lower = SearcInterno.Text.ToLower();` and then use that variable inside the `Task.Run`.

Comment: draw2 is an arrayList and the exception just in the condition that I put it

Comment: An `arrayList` of **what**?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access WPF objects from another thread without a dispatcher. But you don't need it in this case, if you just use:

```
private Task ObtenerDatosd()
{
    string text = SearcInterno.Text.ToLower();

    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        for (int i = draw2.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if(draw2[i].ToString().ToLower().Contains(text))
            {
                //action
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Code action");
            }

        }

    });
}
```

Comment: also send me the exception but this time in the string text, some way to run it?

Comment: @MartinaPrincente Then you'll need to edit your question and add more details, because it shouldn't happen